# How to pass id which is route param to the route resolver service

Tags: angular

How to get the value of Id in the route resolver service because singleInvoice method is called using the invoiceId which is dynamic and in the url for example invoice/4 in this case 4 should be available in resolver service.

```
{
            path: 'invoices',
            component: InvoiceComponent,
            resolve: {
                invoiceDetails: InvoiceResolverService
                },
                data: {
                    title: ' Invoices'
                }
        },
        {
            path: 'invoice/:id',
            component: InvoiceDetailComponent,
            resolve: {
            invoiceDetails: SingleInvoiceResolverService
            },
            data: {
                title: 'Invoice Detail'
            }
}
```

Resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
        import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class SingleInvoiceResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

          constructor(private auth: AuthService, private http: HttpClient) { }
          resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
           return this.auth.singleInvoice(invoiceId);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`route.params['id']` in the resolve method, you can get the id.

Answer (score 0):

In this way you will get an array with the parameters

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        console.log(params);
    }
}
```